# w3c validation for target blank

Tags: html, w3c

Has anyone any idea of a work around for a w3c valid target blank anchor? Scratching my head a bit on this and can't seem to find a solution.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean "workaround"? What are you trying to work around?

Comment: Who voted this down? It's a genuine question, albeit basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target=_blank` is perfectly valid HTML5. Try the below HTML document in the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org)

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title>blank</title></head>
<body><p>A link to <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Example</a>...</body>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. It was coming up as an issue for strict.

Answer (score 1):

1.0 transitional accommodates some old html tags, including target="_blank" so you can try to you use this doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhmtl1/DTD/xhmtl1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Or you can use javascript <a href="sitename.com" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"></a>

Comment: Cool, thanks. It was coming up as an issue for strict.